# On Index page Display IP address in PHP

Tags: php

On My index page I want display the IP address of system or client. For that I wrote this function in separate file.

This is my function:-

```
function getClientIp() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    $_SESSION['myIp'] = $ipaddress;     
}
```

I want to use this function on my index page to display IP address.

Comment: first of all remove `@` form your code. also `session_start();` needed on your both page on top and in your index page just write `echo $_SESSION['myIp'];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:-

remove `@` from your code,skipping errors is not a good practice at all.

add `session_start();` on top of your both page (code page and index page) just after `<?php`

In index page you can fetch value by just doing`echo $_SESSION['myIp'];`

Call the function in your code page:-

```
function getClientIp() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    $_SESSION['myIp'] = $ipaddress;     
}
getClientIp();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your `get_ip.php`

```
session_start(); // this is required on both the pages

function getClientIp() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $_SESSION['myIp'] = $ipaddress;  

}
```

Your `index.php`

```
session_start(); // this is required on both the pages

include("get_ip.php");

echo getClientIp();
```

OR

```
session_start(); // this is required on both the pages

include("get_ip.php");

echo $_SESSION['myIp'];
```